# upgraded "Compiz' and "Unity", now no Unity 3D on screen

Tags: unity, 12.04, compiz

Today when I logged in to my Ubuntu 12.04, the update manager told me of some upgrades.  Compiz and Unity were in those upgrades.

After I installed the upgrades, I can no longer get the Unity panel on the left side of screen or the systray at the top of screen.  I now have to run Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity 2D.  My laptop is a HP Pavilion dv9000 with Nvidia GeForce Go 7600 video.

I tried to run "unity --reset" but it says there are serious issues with compiz.  I have cut & pasted the read out from the terminal below.

```
[09:35:02] xxxxxxx@L01U1204:~$ unity --reset
unity-panel-service: no process found
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x2e00004

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x580005a

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x3600006

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x3200255

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1600002

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1400002

Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/brwright/.compiz/session/10afaca1703486b216133648409481824100000130110002"
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't load plugin '/usr/lib/compiz/libunityshell.so' : /usr/lib/compiz/libunityshell.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5unity4dash10Controller6windowEv
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't load plugin 'unityshell'
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x7000090!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x7000093!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x7000096!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x7000099!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x700009c!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x700009f!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
Initializing annotate options...done
Initializing blur options...done
Initializing clone options...done
Initializing colorfilter options...done
Initializing commands options...done
Initializing cube options...done
Initializing imgjpeg options...done
Initializing kdecompat options...done
Initializing mag options...done
Initializing neg options...done
Initializing obs options...done
Initializing opacify options...done
Initializing put options...done
Initializing resizeinfo options...done
Initializing ring options...done
Initializing rotate options...done
Initializing scaleaddon options...done
Initializing screenshot options...done
Initializing shift options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing switcher options...done
Initializing thumbnail options...done
Initializing unityshell options...done
Initializing water options...done
Initializing winrules options...done
Initializing wobbly options...done
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
Starting gtk-window-decorator
```

As you can see the terminal never comes back to the CI prompt.  I must do a control C to get to the CI prompt, but then the OS is frozen.  I have to reboot and run Unity 2D in able to do anything on my laptop.  I hope I have explained this enough and provided some useful info.  I am at a loss to understand what the problem is, or what exactly what is causing the problem.  Is it Unity or Compiz?  Can anyone help?

Comment: Please, add the bug report, and the fact that it solved it as an answer and accept it. That way this question can be closed with useful information for people with the same problem that can found it in google.

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue with ASUS notebook with ATI 58xx mobile  after using Janitor (Ubuntu Tweak) or updates and could fix it (well at least get 2D) by

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

Still try to get 3D back.

[**Source**](http://forum.parallels.com/printthread.php?t=259137)

Comment: Got 3D back as well :)

Answer (score 1):

> Okay first of all you either DONT'T ctrl-C when running that and you
>   use "sudo service unity stop" and then "unity --reset"...
>
> And then of coarse later go to unity 2d and go to your system
>   settings> appearance>behavior>Reset to defaults, which should fix the
>   problems, it always did for me...
>
> OH OH OH and before you go to back to unity 3D, go to ccsm and go to
>   "Ubuntu Unity plugin" and inside the settings there is a box to the
>   left that lets you enable/disable the plugin...
>
> MAKE SURE IT IS ENABLED!!!

^^Is wrong I' sorry...Here is the solution:
Step 1:

```
sudo apt-get install guake
```

Step 2:
Go to startup applications and make sure guake is in it, if not add it.

Step 3: Launch unity 3d, and wait for guake to pop up, and then hit F12(or whatever key you set it to)

Step 4:
In guake:

```
ccsm
```

Step 5: once compiz config settings manager is up (there shouldn't be any window borders) go to "Ubuntu Unity plugin" and click on it and enable it in the checkbox to the left.

Step 6:
Back in guake make a new tab with "Shift+Ctrl+T" and inside there input:

```
unity --replace
```

Step 7:
Go to this page a respond to this answer telling me your results...

Comment: Ok, sorry about the ctrl-C.  I guess I was just running home to DOS.  I will use the other commands you enclosed.  Thanks.  I will try the mentioned unity2d system settings and let you know the results.  Thanks again.

Comment: I tried all of the above mentioned fixes.  But none seem to have any effect on my problem.  In Unity 3D I still have no "system tray" and no "unity panel".

Comment: Are you sure it is not just "Taking to long to load"? Because that and the fact I didn't have Ubuntu Unity plugin enabled were the only times that the panel didn't show up...

Comment: I really don't think it is just loading to slow.  Example: My wife fixed lunch for me.  I rebooted into Ubuntu 12.05 w/Unity 3D.  $0 minutes later after lunch it was still like it was when I went to lunch.  I have rechecked everything you recommended and all is enabled correctly.  But no Unity 3D.

Comment: I edited the post, please re-read^^^

Comment: I put this in as a "bug", Ubuntu replied that they "confirmed" the issue I was having.  This morning there was an update to Unity in my Update Manager.  I applied it, rebooted using Unity 3D, and it now works like it is suppose to.  So I am going to close this out.  Thanks for you help, I appreciate it.